# Realm- updating all items in array of objects instead of appending only new one

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, persistence, realm

I'm trying to add different journal entries associated with a patient in JournalEntryVC.swift.

My Patient class has an array of journal entries i.e. `let journalEntries = List<Journal>()` My Journal class has properties that represent journal entry attributes i.e. `entryType`, `entryDate` and `entryCaption`.

However, instead of only appending a new journal entry object to the array of journal entries `newPatient.journalEntries.append(myJournal)` when looping over the json in JournalEntryVC.swift, my previously appended journal entries' attributes are also replaced by the most recent journal entry attributes.

For example, `newPatient.journalEntries[0]` has the same string values for `entryCaption` and `entryType` as `newPatient.journalEntries[1]` and so on.

Main problem: Any ideas on how I could add a NEW journal entry with its attributes but without changing journal entry attributes for previously appended journal entries?

Thank you!

```html
//  Patient.swift

import Foundation
import RealmSwift


class Patient: Object {
    
    dynamic var patientName = ""
    dynamic var patientAvatar = ""
    dynamic var patientId = 0
    dynamic var isDietitian = false 

//array of journal entries for each patient
    let journalEntries = List<Journal>() 

    
    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "patientId"
    }
}
```

```html
//  Journal.swift

import Foundation
import RealmSwift


class Journal: Object {

    dynamic var entryId = ""
    dynamic var entryType = ""
    dynamic var entryImg = ""
    dynamic var entryCaption = ""
    dynamic var entryComment = ""
    dynamic var entryCategory = ""
    dynamic var entryDate = ""
   
     
    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "entryId"
    }
  
}
```

```html
//JournalEntryVC.swift

import UIKit
import Alamofire
import BXProgressHUD
import SwiftyJSON
import RealmSwift


class JournalEntryVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


  func reloadInitialData ( ) {
    
    //mutable arrays containing journal entry attributes
    desc.removeAllObjects()
    type.removeAllObjects()
    category.removeAllObjects()
    metric_stat.removeAllObjects()
    entryImages.removeAllObjects()
    dateCreate.removeAllObjects()
    comments.removeAllObjects()
    entryType.removeAllObjects()
    id.removeAllObjects()
    //comments.removeAllObjects()
    content.removeAllObjects()
    patName.removeAllObjects()
    
    
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
        let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://gethealthie.com/entries.json", headers: [
            "access-token": userCreds.objectForKey("access-token")! as! String,
            "client": userCreds.objectForKey("client")! as! String,
            "token-type": userCreds.objectForKey("token-type")! as! String,
            "uid": userCreds.objectForKey("uid")! as! String,
            "expiry": userCreds.objectForKey("expiry")! as! String
            ]).responseJSON { response in
                
                print(response.response)
                
                let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
                
                
                if json.count == 0 {
                    BXProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(self.view);
                }else {
                    
                    //Realm- create object instances of Patient and Journal class
                    let newPatient = Patient()
                    let myJournal = Journal()
                    
                    for i in 0 ..< json.count {
                        
                        let entry = json[i]
                        print(entry)
                        
                        let name = entry["entry_comments"]
                        let k = name["id"]
                        
                        //add entry attributes to mutable arrays
                        self.type.addObject(entry["type"].stringValue)
                        self.desc.addObject(entry["description"].stringValue)
                        self.category.addObject(entry["category"].stringValue)
                        self.metric_stat.addObject(entry["metric_stat"].stringValue)
                        self.dateCreate.addObject(entry["created_at"].stringValue)
                        self.comments.addObject(entry["entry_comments"].rawValue)
                        self.entryType.addObject(entry["category"].stringValue)
                        let posterInfo = entry["poster"]
                        let first = posterInfo["first_name"].stringValue
                        let last = posterInfo["last_name"].stringValue
                        let full = first + " " + last
                        self.patName.addObject(full)
                        self.id.addObject(entry["id"].stringValue)
                        self.entryImages.addObject(entry["image_url"].stringValue)
                        
                        
                        //Realm- access properties in Journal class and set it equal to the current journal entry attribute i.e. json[i]
                        myJournal.entryType = entry["type"].stringValue
                        myJournal.entryCaption = entry["description"].stringValue
                        myJournal.entryCategory = entry["category"].stringValue
                        myJournal.metricStat = entry["metric_stat"].stringValue
                        myJournal.entryDate = entry["created_at"].stringValue
                        //  myJournal.entryComment = entry["entry_comments"].rawValue as! String
                        
                        //append a NEW journal entry to the array of journal entries in Patient class i.e. let journalEntries = List<Journal>() as the json loops thru different journal entries
                        newPatient.journalEntries.append(myJournal)
                        
                        if i == json.count - 1 {
                            // do some task
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                                BXProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(self.view)
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                    //Realm- add newPatient object instance to realm
                    try! self.realm.write {
                        self.realm.add(newPatient)
                        
                    }
                }
                
        }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're instantiating a single instance of Journal outside the for loop, changing the values of that Journal, then appending it to the patient's journalEntries. Try moving `let myJournal = Journal()` inside your for loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I'm new to Swift and Realm, so you nudged me in the right direction. Also, I noticed that data isn't persisting between launches. According to Realm documentation, you must add an object into a Realm within a write transaction in order for it to persist, which I believe I'm doing above. Could there be any other reason that it's not persisting between launches (i.e. after force quitting the app and launching it again)?

Comment: That's likely because you're performing your write in a background thread but using `self.realm`, which I'm guessing was instantiated on the main thread. You can simply do a `let realm = try! Realm()` and use that object to do your write within your thread. This is talked about in much more detail here: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#threading

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm trying to persist data even after force quitting in airplane mode and then launching it again in airplane mode (not sure if that's a valid use case). While the data is persisting and I'm able to show it using a realm object when I launch the app (using wifi) and switch over to airplane mode, it doesn't seem to persist after I force quit it (in airplane mode) and launch it again in airplane mode. I tried to `let realm = try! Realm()` to write within my own thread as you recommended but doesn't seem to work for my use case.